# Keep the outer brackets matching without repeating the inner pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I rewrite this regular expression `/\[.+\]|\{.+\}/` but without repeating the inner pattern `/.+/`?

Must match:

- [abc]
- {abc}

Mustn't match:

- [abc}
- {abc]

Comment: Why? What's wrong with your current expression?

Comment: I believe that it's always good to write as simple as possible, because it improves performance and readability.

Comment: If there is a simpler and more effective way, I'd like to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you could make the `.+` non greedy `.+?`. When greedy, this would match from the opening `[a` till the closing `b]` in this string:

`[abc] {a} [b]`.

Without the `.+` or `.+?` you might use [`\[[^[\n]+?]|{[^{\n]+?}`](https://regex101.com/r/NC826N/1) as an alternative.

This would match:

```
\[       # Match [
[^[\n]+? # Match not [ or a newline one or more times non greedy
]        # match ]
|        # Or
{        # Match {
[^{\n]+? # Match not { or a new line one or more times non greedy
}        # match }
```

Or if this is only about `abc`, you could use `\[abc]|{abc}`

When running both regexes on regex101.com and prce selected, they give the same number of execution steps so I think that this would not be faster.

[`\[.+?\]|\{.+?\}`](https://regex101.com/r/mPJgAW/1)

[`\[[^[\n]+?]|{[^{\n]+?}`](https://regex101.com/r/NC826N/2)